# Джава как узнать текущую раскладку клавиатуры?

Tags: java, клавиатура

Джава как узнать текущую раскладку клавиатуры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Источник: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php#language

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
    String localeString = ims.getLocale();
    Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
    String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
    EditText languageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLanguage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Следует быть осторожным с примером. На эмуляторе с Android 6.0 пример работал корректно. На реальных устройствах у меня корректно определялся русский язык, но при переключении на английский язык выдавал пустую строку или значение "zz". В этом случае можно прибегнуть к условиям if и проверять ожидаемое значение.